# Tab 'Caching Rules' is gone in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, caching, azure-blob-storage

As the title of this post describes my problem...

I cannot find the tab "Caching Rules" in Azure Blob Storage managing page.

Is there an other tab for these actions?

I could not find any references of these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in the CDN,

In the Azure portal, select a CDN profile, then select the endpoint for the blob. You will be able to see Caching rules.

Read more [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content)

Comment: Thanks forthe answer! Now I have found it. Now I have an other problem. I have no option to add rules. I have chosen for the Standard Vorizan Tier.

Comment: Found it! I need to choose for a Standard Akamai or Standard Verizon tier